# Opening multiple 'aside' using angular-strap

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

We are using the 'aside' for composing email in our application. When opening a 'aside', if any other 'aside' is exists(Composing multiple emails at a time) then it has to adjust the position left/right. When I am changing the url or state of the routing, need to close all the existing 'aside' panels. Can any one provide the solution?